# FreePascal syntax error "invalid qualifier", but it compiles in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7, freepascal

The code below compiles in Delphi 7, but gives an error in FPC. Is there any mode switch that makes it compile?

```
procedure Test;
type
  TArray = array of Integer;
  TArrayFunc = function: TArray;
var
 a: TArray;
 f: TArrayFunc;
 i: integer;
begin
 i := f[0]; //* FPC: "Error: Illegal qualifier"
 i := f()[0]; //* Compiles in D7 and FPC
end;
```

Comment: just use `f()[0]`

Comment: Did you have the same problem if you put FPC into [Delphi mode](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progse74.html) using `{$MODE Delphi}`?

Comment: Yes. Today i tried all {$mode} and {$modeswith} directives, and it can't be compiled, So i think, FPC-3.2.2 does'n support this syntax. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in FPC 3.2.2. I just fixed it in FPC 3.3.1: https://gitlab.com/freepascal.org/fpc/source/-/commit/ec28b7586c4b74823555f196772743fe9bfa3dde

Comment: Great! Trivia: `_LECKKLAMMER` means [**l**inke](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/links) [**eck**ige **Klammer**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klammer_(Zeichen)#Eckige_Klammern) (I never encountered the potential noun "_Eckklammer"). As such it also sounds like [leck](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/lecken)-Klammer (licking/leak bracket).